# Can you use the browser specific prefix in front of all css tags?

Tags: css, tags, longest-prefix

Can you use the browser specific prefix in front of all standard tags?

e.g.

```
#div{

 padding:20px;
-moz-padding-bottom:10px;

}
```

is the above valid CSS for ensuring Firefox has a different bottom padding to all other browsers?

Comment: Why would you *want* to do this? Just curious...

Comment: My design is rendering differntly in firefox when compared to safari, as such I want to target firefox specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a prefix for targetting a browser, it's a prefix that is used for specific non-standard properties like `-moz-opacity` or `-moz-padding-start`. It's not available for the standard properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it, but the style will be ignored by browsers who don't understand it and the CSS won't pass [CSS Validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Yes, you can try to use anything you like as a style, like `eye-color` or `blast-radius`... ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, no, there isn't a prefix for things that *are* standardized, since they're the same property cross-browser (or *should* be, don't take this for granted in IE).

Instead of what you're after with this prefix, I'd instead look at a completely different approach...**taking out the differences** in rendering, instead of trying to fix them, at least as many as possible.

[Take a look at a CSS reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), to normalize the padding and such across browsers, *then* look at fixing any remaining quirks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest.

```
-webkit-text-stroke
```

Works in Firefox browsers as well.